# What is the point of types of literals in C++?

Tags: c++, literals

I'm new to C++ and I'm using C++ Primer to study.

To me, it makes sense for variables to have "sub-types" like `long` and `long long` for `int`, so that they can accommodate larger values, even if they're initialized with a not so large value.

But I can't seem to wrap my head around why one might need to override the default type of, say, an integer literal such as `42` to make it `long long` instead of the default `int`? It's not like the literal will ever have to hold another value, since it's practically a constant.

Comment: Generally you don't need to "override" the type of literal values. But sometimes it's needed, when you are using two different types in an incompatible way, or when behavior of mixing types is not well-defined.

Comment: Rational is history, the size of int/long are not fixed between platforms (8/16/32/64 bit architectures). In the end I usually end up using types like std::uint8_t, std::int32_t etc for portable code. To make constants of a specific type use `static constexpr <type> constant = 42;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But in that case, can't we just change the type of the variable, instead of the literal?

Comment: Please note that I didn't mention "variable", only "value"... Take the example from [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76753574/440558), what if the left-hand value is a literal value but the right-hand value is a variable (e.g. `1 << bits_to_shift`). Changing the type of the variable won't help, and to protect yourself against the problem mentioned in the answer the solution is the same: Explicitly give the literal `1` a specific type (like `1ULL` or similar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a literal directly in an expression (rather than just initializing a variable with a specified type from it), then the type of the literal will be important because arithmetic expressions are affected by the specific integer types.

For example:

```
1 << 32
```

Here `1` has type `int` and so, on a system where `int` is 32 bit wide, this will have undefined behavior: You can't left-shift an integer more than by w-1 where `w` is its width.

On the other hand

```
1LL << 32
```

is guaranteed to be fine, because `1LL` has type `long long` and that type is guaranteed to be at least 64 bit wide.

Similarly, overload resolution may choose different functions to call depending on the type of an operand/argument. So using `1LL` as an argument instead of `1` may call a different overload with different behavior.

Comment: "1LL has type long long and that type is guaranteed to be at least 64 bit wide" - strictly speaking I don't think that is technically correct. `int` is defined to be at least 16bit and `long` is only specified as being *at least as large as `int`*. `long long` is specified as being *at least as large as `long`*. So an implementation where `int`, `long` and `long long` are all 16bit (or all 32bit) would be conforming.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, both C and C++ specify minimum widths for all types, see e.g. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#tab:basic.fundamental.width. On architectures that can't do arithmetic of sizes that large natively, the compiler must emulate them with library functions.

Comment: Ohh, perhaps I'm remembering some older version of the standard. I'm pretty certain the rules *used to be* like I described.

Comment: Indeed, C++17 draft has no such table in [basic.fundamental](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#subsection.6.9.1) and no remarks about "width" whatsoever in this section. It seems to be C++20 addition.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Before C++20 two's complement couldn't be assumed, so defining the range in form of width wasn't possible. The minimum range was instead defined through the `<climits>` macros with reference to the C standard, which defines e.g. `LLONG_MAX` as at least `+9223372036854775807` with effectively the same result.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Except for the addition of `long long` with a minimum of 64 bits, I think all the other requirements have always been the same in all C and C++ standard. So before C99/C++11 it was possible to have all types be 32bit though. And I am pretty sure there are also embedded C (and maybe C++?) compilers that simply aren't standard-conforming.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now. An alternative to situations where this is needed can be to define a variable with type LL and use that in the expression instead of directly using the literal, right? A worse alternative, but an alternative nonetheless.

Comment: Is `int a = 123` the same as `int a = 123LL`? And is the default type of an integer literal 
outside the range of `int`, for example `12313123123123`, automatically gonna be `L`/`LL`, depending on their ranges? If not, then it wouldn't make sense to define `long a = 123123123123`, and we'd have to use `long a = 123123123123L`, right?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu • No, yes, mu.

Comment: @Eljay Well, what's the difference between `int a = 123` an `int a = 123LL`? Won't `123LL`  be converted to `int` when assigning it to `a`?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu "_An alternative to situations where this is needed can be to define a variable with type LL and use that in the expression instead of directly using the literal, right?_": Yes, however, some context require a _constant expression_, i.e. an expression that can be evaluated at compile-time. For example the size of an array must be a constant expression. A literal can always be used for that, but generally a variable can't.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu In C++ that's not a big deal because you can use `constexpr` to make a variable usable in constant expressions, but in C from which all of this is inherited, originally there was no way to use a variable's value in a constant expression.

Comment: "_Is int a = 123 the same as int a = 123LL?_": Yes (i.e. the effects are the same) "_And is the default type of an integer literal outside the range of int, for example 12313123123123, automatically gonna be L/LL, depending on their ranges?_": Almost yes. It depends on the kind of integer literal. See the table in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal for exact details. "_If not, then it wouldn't make sense to define long a = 123123123123, and we'd have to use long a = 123123123123L, right?_": The literal always has a type that can hold its value, so that's not a problem.

Comment: The difference is that 123LL will be converted to int when assigning it to a (at compile time).  Whereas 123 will not be converted to int when assigning it to a, because it is already an int.  If you ignore the difference, then they're the same.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu However, it is important to realize that a `-` sign cannot be part ofan  integer literal and so is not taken into account for my above statement. Integer literals themselves are never negative. So, it can happen that `-X` where `X` is a sequence of digits actually has undefined behavior because `X` may have a type that can hold `X` but not its negated value.

Comment: @Eljay user17732522 Gotcha, thanks!